# What's the best way of deploying a schema object to two different databases in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

We have two databases, A and B. A contains tables that should also be deployed to B; however, A should always be considered as the master of those tables. We don't want to duplicate the schema object scripts. We do not want to simply reference A's table from B - they need to be separate, duplicated tables.

As far as I can see, there are two ways to achieve this:

1. Partial projects: export the shared schema objects to a partial project (.files) file, and import it into the B's database project
2. Adding shared schema object files to the B's database project as links.

These both have the disadvantage that you need to explicitly specify files - you cannot specify a folder, meaning that any time a schema object that needs sharing is added to A's database project, then either the partial project export would need to be run again, or the new file added as a link to B's project.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these techniques? Are there any better ways of achieving this that I may have missed? Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you generating the schemas? Is it a Db project/Arbitrary Db Context/SQL/EF/L2SQL/?? Assuming db projects, You could probably get 90% of the way there through clever use of source control branching/merging - Get all common elements for A and B, call it A. Branch and call it B. Add other objects to B. Now, whenever A is updated, you can do a branch merge from A into B. If A has objects that should never be in B, the merge is a little more complex but not unreasonably so.

Comment: It's a normal SQL Server 2008 Database Project. There will be objects in A that should not appear in B. I hadn't considered merging. My initial reaction is that it would be prone to going wrong as it's another thing for the developer to remember to do, and merging is nobody's favourite job at the best of times. Ideally we want to automate this as much as possible. Furthermore, the deployment chaps may well object to creating separate branches that will contribute to the same overall deployment; we use branches to separate release versions and different products.

Comment: Understandable - and with objects in A not going to B, that makes it even less attractive. FWIW I've found TFS's merging to be pretty painless as it's code-intent aware (although still not perfect). In any case, if you're already branching/merging, it would be non-ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Projects are [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the VS2012 RC release, which makes me think that I shouldn't use them. Furthermore, it appears that [Composite Projects](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/ssdtblog/~3/4AsOHVQJekA/composite-projects-and-schema-compare.aspx) within [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) (SSDT) may be the long term solution.

I've discovered that it is possible to link to entire folders by editing the dbproj file manually. For example:

```
<Build Include="..\SourceDatabase\Schema Objects\Tables\*.sql">
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
  <Link>Schema Objects\Tables\%(FileName).sql</Link>
</Build>
```

This works quite nicely, so it will be our preferred solution until we evaluate SSDT. The main drawback that I've found with it so far is that it will include all files in the source database's folders, including those that are not included in the source database project.